# Single source for iPad, androidPad, and Windows 8/HTML?

Tags: android, ipad, html, windows-8

Is there a way to write code once that will run locally on the iPad, android, and Windows 8 (HTML 5 mode)? All three support HTML 5 and if we were running on a server and displaying on a browser in each this would be easy.

But we want to run locally, both for a faster response and for times there is no net connection (like on an airplane). Is there a way to accomplish this?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 2):

Try [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com), It might be answer to your questions.

Comment: +1 for phonegap. I think that these kind of libraries that are using browser and javascript can be a good approach to reach many platforms with one codebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your app in HTML5, it'll only be able to target the features supported by HTML5. While HTML5 support some offline scenarios by caching content locally, understand that this scenario isn't yet fully specced, standardized or implemented consistently by all browser vendors on all platforms.

If offline, perf and/or platform-specific features are important, you're going to need to lay bits down on the target device(s).

I strongly recommend [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) which enables you to use write .NET applications that target Windows, Linux & OSX and [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)'s MonoTouch (for iOS) and Mono for Android.

Understand, however, that the UI portions of your app will need to be implemented independenty because each platform's UI concepts, structure, techniques and features vary so widely. So be sure to carefully separate your core business logic and engine should be partitioned into a cleanly separated assembly that can be reused across all your supported platforms.

Comment: This is a really interesting idea. We were thinking at first it would be HTML5 local on Windows 8 and displayed in a browser hitting a server for the rest (so running on a .NET server). But this is a really interesting approach. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it was of interest. If you like my reply, please mark as answer :)